# What do "steady" and "steadily" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “To fall in love is easy, even to remain in it is not difficult; our human loneliness is cause enough. **But it is a hard quest worth making to find a comrade through whose *steady* presence one becomes *steadily* the person one desires to be.**”

—   Anna Louise Strong

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Can you explain more about what you're having trouble understanding in this quote? What's the most you can figure out (by looking at dictionaries or searching the web) about what it means? If we don't know what you're having trouble with, it will be difficult to answer without just getting lucky.

Comment: "it is a hard quest worth making to find a comrade through whose steady presence one becomes steadily the person one desires to be". I do not know what exactly the sentence means, there are the words "steady" and "steadily" make me confused.

Comment: Did you look up steady in the dictionary? It means ['not changing and not interrupted' or 'gradually and in an even and regular way'](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/steady_1?q=steady) and steadily has a very similar definition (except that it is an adverb) I don't understand why the dictionary isn't helping you - can you explain a little more please?

Answer (score 1):

Putting in simple words,

> Humans fall in love too easily because they're lonely. But it is hard to find someone who stays by your side and lets you be who you want to be. It's hard but it is worth it.

Interpretation always implies in different views. That is mine. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Falling in love is easy, and staying in love is also easy because people are afraid of being lonely. The difficult part [quest=the search] is finding that special someone who helps you become the person you want to be (i.e. a better person) in life. But it's worth it in the end.